# php error: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I'm making an API for my project with php and mssql (sql server). I wrote this code but its giving me erros. I have checked the parameters and the values but I can't see the problem. any help would be appreciated.
The error is this:  SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in C:\wamp\www\sarfeh\api\objects\user.php on line 40
I have marked the line 40 in this code bellow.
Ans this is what $hash has: $2y$10$BTog4ZdjkrDsH9Hw/FjuD.myHiz61o6SOUDy4KuvoB2dGDQV9Vl4u

**EDIT:**
If I pass the password without hashing (the 11111), this works, but with hashing I get the error.

function create(){

```
    /
    // insert query
    $query = "INSERT INTO " . $this->table_name . "
    (first_name,last_name,phone,password_hash)
    values (:first_name,:last_name,:phone,':password')";

    /$this->first_name="arassssh2";
    $this->last_name="arasssh2";
    $this->phone="326981";
    $this->password="111111";
    // prepare the query
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
    // bind the values
    $stmt->bindParam(':first_name', $this->first_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':last_name', $this->last_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':phone', $this->phone, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $hash = password_hash($this->password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':password', $hash); //line 40


    // execute the query, also check if query was successful
    if($stmt->execute()){
        return true;
    }

    return false;

}
```

Comment: Remove `'` before and after `:password`. Change ` (:first_name,:last_name,:phone,':password')` to ` (:first_name,:last_name,:phone,:password)`.

Comment: Why you are giving `':password'` in your query? Refer this for more info https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to surround your parameter name with `'`. Remove `'` before and after `:password`. Change

```
$query = "INSERT INTO " . $this->table_name . "
    (first_name,last_name,phone,password_hash)
    values (:first_name,:last_name,:phone,':password')
";
```

to

```
 $query = "INSERT INTO " . $this->table_name . "
    (first_name,last_name,phone,password_hash)
    values (:first_name,:last_name,:phone,:password)
";
```

Comment: I removed the ' , the error changed to this:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[22001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]String or binary data would be truncated.

Comment: @ArashMohammadi Your `$hash` variable length is more than column width in SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks! That was the problem! in Sql Server the password_hash field was 50, changed it to 250 and it worked! you saved me hours thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe `line 40` should be :

```
 $stmt->bindParam(':password', $hash, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Comment: The @Zhorov answer solved it for me, but Thanks for reminding me the param type.

Comment: You might consider upvoting the answer if it helped in any way :)